# HTML5: after home button click, document.ready() does not fire on target page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have an HTML5 (+JQM) page:

```
...
<div data-role="header">
  <a data-rel="home" ... href="index.html"></a>
</div>
...
```

after home button is pressed, and home page ("index.html") loads,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

does not fire; nor does fire

```
$("div[data-role*='page']").live('pageshow', function() {
```

I need to run some code *every time* my home page is loaded, doesn't matter if it's loaded directly or after a "home" button...

Comment: have you tried `$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageshow', function () {/*your code*/ }); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) use the PageInit event please.  This is the recommended event to use if you need to code to run every time your page loads.

However, after my being dumb moment, I realise what you're doing.  But I can't find a "data-rel" attribute of "home" on the docs page? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html

I assume you have a multi-page template - using index.html and another.html file.  I suspect you'll need to add

```
data-rel="external"
```

rather than "home" when navigating between the html files?

Comment: Thanks... I missed that big warning on JQM events docs page... :-( However, not even pageinit does fire when the page is reloaded after a "home" button press...

Comment: I'm not sure downvoting a correct answer is going to get you much more help, but if you're talking about the "hardware" home button on a mobile I think you can only manage events from that (like Pause, Resume) through a native app, or a framework like Phonegap.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to downvote, I only wanted to withdraw the upvote I gave, after I checked pageinit does not fire, either... :-( However, I do not mean a "hardware" button at all, I mean - as it should be clear from my post - a [ <a data-rel="home" ... Ihref="index.html"></a> ] in my header... If you update your answer I'll be happy to retire my downvote...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I had (I didn't mention it in the question, sorry...):

```
data-direction="reverse"
```

in my  home link... Without it, and using data-rel="external", as Dave R suggested, everything runs ok...